# Accessing value of Editable field in repeat control

Tags: xpages

How can I access the value of an computed field in a repeat control?
In the example below, I have cfT5Budget in a repeat control.  I want to be able to access the value of each of the cfT5Budget control (repeat1:0:cfT5Budget, repeat1:1:cfT5Budget, etc..)

I want to be able to have that same value replicated into my second repeat control.  I will be doing other stuff in the second control but for this example, it's just a simple code.

```
<xp:table>
    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" var="rowItem1" indexVar="indexVar1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:['a', 'b', 'c']}]]></xp:this.value>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:text escape="true" id="cfT5Budget" value="#{javascript:5 + indexVar1}">
                </xp:text>
            </xp:td>

        </xp:tr>
    </xp:repeat>
</xp:table>
<xp:table>
    <xp:repeat id="repeat2" var="rowItem2" indexVar="indexVar2">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent('repeat1').getValue()}]]></xp:this.value>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:text escape="true" id="cfT5Budget2" value="#{javascript:VALUE OF cfT5Budget GOES HERE}">
                </xp:text>
            </xp:td>

        </xp:tr>
    </xp:repeat>
</xp:table>
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Put repeat2 inside repeat1 and use the variable rowItem1 to get the value.

Comment: maybe that was a bad example.  Forget repeat2, let's say i have a computed field after repeat1 and i want to access the first inputText1 in repeat1, how do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: use data binding.

The long answer:

In MVC your code should not interact with the View (a.k.a the fields), but rather the model (a.k.a the data). So instead of computing the values like in your example, you bind them using the variable name provided in the repeat.

You interact with that collection (Array) not the fields. This makes code easier and more robust since the code doesn’t need to care what UI element is used.

Hope that helps

Comment: That was a bad example i provided.  I've modified my code to reflect what i'm looking for.  My field in the repeat is computed and without binding it to a scope variable, is there a way to access the data of repeat1:0:cfT5Budget or repeat1:1:cfT5Budget?

Comment: My answer stands: bind it. I like java collections with simple classes. Can do wonders in calculating whatever. In the UI keep it simple and bind. V doesn’t stand for computation

Comment: You're repeats are iterating over the same data.So, as Stephan says, why set the `value` property of the second by looking to the `value` property of the first?Bind to the datasource.
Regardless, row A in repeat 1 = row A in repeat 2. If you have a computed field in one repeat, why try and get the value from outside the repeat? If it's inexpensive, repeat the computation. Otherwise, bind the repeats to a collection which contains (as properties) what you want to display. 
Typically, server-side a "row" in a repeat does not exist outside the scope of that row, see https://youtu.be/t7j_MR5uzCA

Comment: Great thank you. That's what I wanted to know, if the row is accessible outside of the repeat.  Binding it is.. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad it works for you. Spread the idea: data binding is the path to happiness. We’ve seen too much getComponent().getValue()